# Getting a Fragment Dialog to appear after first click on EditText Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-dialogfragment

I'm building a registration form and trying to get my `fragment dialog` to appear as soon as the `EditText` field is focused. Currently when it first gets focus it shows the keyboard and then when tapped again it brings up the Dialog. The main goal of this question is get the Dialog to appear as it gains focus. If you can also help with code to stop the keyboard appearing for this `EditText` only as well that would be amazing, I may just leave that for another question.

**layout xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRegDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvEmail"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Registration Due:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etRegDate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tvRegDate"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tvFirstName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etLastName"
    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
    />
```

**java code**

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    }



}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");



}
```

Comment: remove default focus set to edit text view in xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are using `onClick()` instead of it you have to use `setOnFocusChangeListener()` this event will fire ASAP when your `EditText` gain focus.

**Example**

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(
     new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
             if(!hasFocus){
                 // show dialog here
             }
        }
});
```